# Scala: macro to create an instance from a class body

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros

I am building a DSL in Scala, and for that, I need to store "instances" of a class (`Parent` in this case), except these "instances" must be re-created several times at runtime. So instead I am storing "constructor functions" - a lambda that makes the instance.

consider the following code - imagine that `userVar` can change at runtime and the updated value must be used when constructing the instances.

```
class Parent {
  def func(param: Any): Unit = { ... }
}

class User {
  def construct(constr: => Parent): ParentWrapper = { ... }

  var userVar = 13

  construct(new Parent {
    func(1)
    func(userVar)
  }

  construct(new Parent {
    func(userVar)
  }
}
```

A more natural way of expressing what I want would be this (using the above definitions):

```
class User {
  var userVar = 13
  object ObjectA extends Parent {
    func(1)
    func(userVar)
  }

  construct(ObjectA)
}
```

However, that seems impossible, given that `ObjectA` is created immediately, and doesn't have a "constructor".

I am thinking, with some creative use of macros, I could instead do this:

```
class User {
  var userVar = 13

  constructMacro {
    func(1)
    func(userVar}
  }
}
```

and have the `constructMacro` convert the code to `construct(new Parent {code block goes here})`.

How would I do that?

Or is there a better way to avoid the awkward `construct(new Parent{...})` call? My requirement is that somewhere in the `User` class a reference is stored that I can repeatedly call and get new instances of the `Parent` definition that reflect new values used in their construction -- and the `construct` call should ideally return a wrapper object for that reference.

Comment: Also you can annotate a variable (see update to my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately macros will not help.

Macro annotations (which expand before type checking) [can't annotate code blocks](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html):

```
@constructMacro {
  func(1)
  func(userVar)
}
```

is illegal.

Def macros (which expand during type checking) [have their arguments type checked before macros are expanded](http://www.scala-archive.org/Expand-macros-before-typechecking-its-arguments-trees-td4641188.html). So

```
constructMacro {
  func(1)
  func(userVar)
}
```

doesn't compile:

```
Error: not found: value func
      func(1)
Error: not found: value func
      func(userVar)
```

That's the reason why macro [`shapeless.test.illTyped`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/test/typechecking.scala#L31) accepts a string rather than code block:

```
illTyped("""
  val x: Int = "a"
""")
```

rather than

```
illTyped {
  val x: Int = "a"
}
```

So the closest you can implement is

```
constructMacro("""
  func(1)
  func(userVar)
""")

def constructMacro(block: String): ParentWrapper = macro constructMacroImpl

def constructMacroImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(block: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val q"${blockStr: String}" = block
  val block1 = c.parse(blockStr)
  q"""construct(new Parent {
    ..$block1
  })"""
}
```

---

You can annotate a variable

```
@constructMacro val x = {
  func(1)
  func(userVar)
}

//         becomes
// val x: ParentWrapper = construct(new Parent {
//   func(1)
//   func(userVar)
// })

@compileTimeOnly("enable macro paradise to expand macro annotations")
class constructMacro extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro constructMacroImpl.impl
}

object constructMacroImpl {
  def impl(c: whitebox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    annottees match {
      case q"$mods val $tname: $tpt = { ..$stats }" :: Nil =>
        q"$mods val $tname: ParentWrapper = construct(new Parent { ..$stats })"

      case _ =>
        c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Not a val")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you just need to change `object` to `def` in the `ObjectA` block:

```
class User {
  var userVar = 13
  def makeParent = new Parent {
    func(1)
    func(userVar)
  }

  construct(makeParent)
}
```

and it'll do what you want.

Comment: Thing is, the Parent objects can be nested. and once you're inside the first Parent, every other Parent can be a class or an object, as appropriate. What I want to avoid is having to teach the users of the DSL that "you can use class or object, but the root `Parent` is special and always must be a class and you must  pass something that calls `new Parent` to `construct`". It would be nicer to just say that the root is a bare code block, and convert it to an instance under the hood.