# Compilation failure is confirmed at the moment of accessing typeSignature of a specific symbol at macro expansion

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I had to look at specific declarations in the macro and examine them individually.
Many such errors occurred when trying to examine the akka stream declaration.

```scala
def getType(symbol: Symbol): Type = {
  symbol.typeSignature
}
```

```
[error] error while loading SmallSortedMap$Entry, class file '/Users/xxx/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-protobuf_2.13/jars/akka-protobuf_2.13-2.5.23.jar(akka/protobuf/SmallSortedMap$Entry.class)' is broken
[error] (class java.util.NoSuchElementException/key not found: K)
```

In this way, it seems that an error occurs when accessing a typeSygnature for a specific symbol.

I want to ignore this, hide it and compile successfully

```scala
def getType(symbol: Symbol): Option[Type] = {
  Try {
    symbol.typeSignature
  }.getOrElse(None) // Can not capture
}
```

However, it seems that "class is broken" can not be caught by "Try".
For example, packages with this symbol are excluded as blacklists. As a result, complex maintenance may occur each time a dependency is added.

```scala
  if (symbol.isNotBroken) {
    symbol.typeSignature
  }
```

Is there a way to solve this way?

### Try

I tried typeCheck.

```
implicit class RichVectorSymbol(value: Vector[Symbol]) {
    def accessible: Vector[Symbol] = {
      value.flatMap { x =>
        scala.util.Try {
          print(s"typecheck ${x.fullName} ")
          c.typecheck(q"${c.parse(x.fullName)}", silent = true)
        } match {
          case Success(r) if r.nonEmpty =>
            println("Success")
            Some(r.symbol)
          case Failure(e) =>
            println("Fail")
            c.warning(c.enclosingPosition, e.getMessage)
            None
          case _ =>
            println("Empty")
            None
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

as a result.

```
// Success case
typecheck akka.event.jul.Logger Success
typecheck akka.io.dns.CachePolicy Success
typecheck akka.io.dns.DnsSettings Success

// Fail case
typecheck com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper$2 [error] error while loading ObjectMapper$2, class file '/Users/xxxxx/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/bundles/jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar(com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper$2.class)' is broken
[error] (class java.util.NoSuchElementException/key not found: T)
Empty
typecheck akka.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$Entry [error] error while loading SmallSortedMap$Entry, class file '/Users/xxxxx/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-protobuf_2.13/jars/akka-protobuf_2.13-2.5.23.jar(akka/protobuf/SmallSortedMap$Entry.class)' is broken
[error] (class java.util.NoSuchElementException/key not found: K)
Empty
```

Like this, I've been forced to compile error.
The sample is here.
https://github.com/giiita/scaladia/blob/master/scaladia-macro/src/main/scala/com/phylage/scaladia/internal/AutoDIExtractor.scala

#### Debugging

After reading the scala source code, I was throwing a clear IOException internally, but I could not catch it, so I reported the issue just in case
https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11611

Comment: Is it compile error? Compile errors can't be caught at runtime.

Comment: Sorry, this is a problem with macro expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In macro you can try

```
c.typecheck(q"${... some tree ...}", silent = true)
```

If tree doesn't typecheck this returns empty tree.

---

The thing seems to be in dollar sign in `akka.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$Entry`. If we replace `$` with `#` or `.` then error `class file is broken` changes to `class SmallSortedMap in package protobuf cannot be accessed in package akka.protobuf`, this is because `SmallSortedMap` [has](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-protobuf/src/main/java/akka/protobuf/SmallSortedMap.java#L91) package-private (Java default) access.

I managed to catch the error when I feed type as a string parameter to macro and use `#` or `.` instead of `$`.

```
  def foo[T]: Unit = macro fooImpl[T]

  def fooImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    try {
      println(weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol.typeSignature)
    } catch {
      case ex: Throwable => println(ex)
    }
    q"()"
  }

  def foo1(tpe: String): Unit = macro foo1Impl

  def foo1Impl(c: blackbox.Context)(tpe: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val q"${tpeStr: String}" = tpe
    try {
      println(c.typecheck(c.parse(s"val ${c.freshName()}: $tpeStr = ???")))
//      println(c.typecheck(c.parse(tpeStr), mode = c.TYPEmode))
//      println(c.typecheck(c.parse(tpeStr), mode = c.TYPEmode).symbol.companion.typeSignature)
//      println(c.typecheck(c.parse(tpeStr), mode = c.TYPEmode).tpe.typeSymbol.typeSignature)
//      println(c.typecheck(c.parse(tpeStr), mode = c.TYPEmode).tpe)
    } catch {
      case ex: Throwable => println(ex)
    }
    q"()"
  }

  foo[Int]
//  foo[akka.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$Entry]//Error:scalac: error while loading SmallSortedMap$Entry, class file '.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-protobuf_2.13/jars/akka-protobuf_2.13-2.5.23.jar(akka/protobuf/SmallSortedMap$Entry.class)' is broken(class java.util.NoSuchElementException/key not found: K)
//  foo[akka.protobuf.SmallSortedMap#Entry]//Error: class SmallSortedMap in package protobuf cannot be accessed in package akka.protobuf
//  foo[akka.protobuf.SmallSortedMap.Entry]//Error:class SmallSortedMap in package protobuf cannot be accessed in package akka.protobuf

//  foo1("Int")
//  foo1("akka.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$Entry")//Error:scalac: error while loading SmallSortedMap$Entry, class file '.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-protobuf_2.13/jars/akka-protobuf_2.13-2.5.23.jar(akka/protobuf/SmallSortedMap$Entry.class)' is broken (class java.util.NoSuchElementException/key not found: K)
  foo1("akka.protobuf.SmallSortedMap#Entry")//Warning:scalac: scala.reflect.macros.TypecheckException: class SmallSortedMap in package protobuf cannot be accessed in package akka.protobuf
  foo1("akka.protobuf.SmallSortedMap.Entry")//Warning:scalac: scala.reflect.macros.TypecheckException: class SmallSortedMap in package protobuf cannot be accessed in package akka.protobuf
```

Otherwise when you call `foo[... SomeType ...]`, `SomeType` is typechecked before macro  `foo` is expanded.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56754290/5249621

http://www.scala-archive.org/Expand-macros-before-typechecking-its-arguments-trees-td4641188.html

Comment: I tried but I got a compile error. Look at Try in the text.

Comment: @omarun `scala.util.Try` doesn't catch fatal errors. Try to replace with `try {...} catch { case ex => ... }` block.

Comment: @omarun I updated my answer. I managed to catch the error when I feed type as a string parameter to macro and use `#` or `.` instead of `$`.

Comment: @omarun not all internal compile errors can be propagated so that you can catch them in macro. For example typecheck error in implicit candidate normally shouldn't be propagated to user, it should silently remove this implicit from list of candidates.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer.
For this problem, "class file is broken" was an IOException internally. But do you think it is a bug that you could not catch with "try catch"?

Comment: @omarun No, I don't think it's a bug, it's an absent feature. With ordinary function you also don't catch exception: `def f(x: Any): Unit = {
    try {
      x
    } catch {
      case ex: Throwable => println(ex)
    }
  }`
  `f(throw new Exception("AAA"))`. But if you change argument to lazy `def f(x: => Any)` then you will. With def macros we have eagerly typechecked arguments but don't have lazily typechecked.