# Postpone implicit resolution until macro expansion

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, implicit, scala-macros

Consider trivial macro:

```
def test[A](a: A): Unit = macro testImpl[A]

def testImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)(a: c.Expr[A]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
  import c.universe._
  println("Test running")
  c.Expr[Unit](q"")
}
```

and its invocation

```
def foo(a: String)(implicit b: Int): Unit = ???

test(foo("123"))
```

It gives an error that

```
[error] Main.scala:19:18: could not find implicit value for parameter b: Int
[error]     test(foo("123"))
```

Is it possible to defer implicit resolution until macro expansion time or writing macro annotation is necessary for such cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On contrary to macro annotations annotating untyped annottees, parameters of a def macro are always typechecked before the macro is expanded. And typechecking includes implicit resolution.

You can also try to make a parameter of def macro `String`

```
test("""foo("123")""")
```

(use `c.parse` in the definition of `test`).

http://www.scala-archive.org/Expand-macros-before-typechecking-its-arguments-trees-td4641188.html

[Scala: macro to create an instance from a class body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56735579/scala-macro-to-create-an-instance-from-a-class-body)

Comment: Nice workaround with passing expressions as `String`, thanks.